# Javascript latitude and longitude inside a polygon

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for solutions regarding a specific point being inside a polygon, but the threads I've been reading have usually involved an API being called like GMaps. I wonder if this can be done with purely Javascript, through the use of an algorithm? (I did read through Dan Sunday's algorithm)

Answer (score -1):

Yup, it sure can.

For instance, [substack's `point-in-polygon`](https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon) looks like a promising library to do just that.